# How to correctly apply regular expression to full file in C#?

Tags: c#, regex

I have a CSV file that contains information of this type:

```
INC 1|Column1|Column2|Column3
INC 2|Column1|Column2
Column 3 Column 4|Column3
INC 3|Column1|Column2
Column 3|Column3
INC 4|Column1|Column2|Column3
```

And with the following regular expression I am trying to remove the line breaks in the whole file so that it looks like this:

```
INC 1|Column1|Column2|Column3
INC 2|Column1|Column2 Column 3 Column 4|Column3
INC 3|Column1|Column2|Column3
INC 4|Column1|Column2 Column3|Column3
```

This works for me when I validate it in https://regex101.com/r/WHkOP2/1 and do the replace with $1

However in C# it does not work,

This is the code:

```
string file = File.ReadAllText(archivoCSVRoute);
file=Regex.Replace(file, @"(\w|\s+(?!\|))\n", "$1");
File.WriteAllText(sRuta + "\\" + archivo + "_copy3.csv", file);
```

Is it possible to apply some such regular expression to the entire file?

Comment: You might want to loop through the file line-by-line and apply the regex that way

Comment: It does not work in regex101, https://regex101.com/r/leVGFc/1. Please provide a working example.

Comment: What is your criteria for merging lines anyways? Is your rule basically "remove line break if line does not contain 3 pipes"?

Comment: I need to remove line breaks when the row doesn't end with character | and this I need to do without needing to go through the file

Comment: @MonkeyZeus like this: https://regex101.com/r/WHkOP2/1    the | character was missing at the end of where each row ends

Comment: In my defense, it was missing from your sample. Please edit your question to fix these mistakes and provide the regex101 link. People on Stack Overflow tend to skip questions which are poorly written and you end up with a comment thread like this one.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus  thank you, I already corrected the question

Comment: Do you really need to use Regex here? Just write manual code. Also, what you do mean with "without needing to go through the file"? You do realize, that the Regex-engine will have to do just this (just without you "seeing" it)?

Comment: @Christian.K Presumably OP doesn't want to load the entire file into memory but rather read it line by line because of memory limitations.

Comment: Yes, but a simple Regex like the code shown, will do just exactly that. (ReadAllText/WriteAllText)

Comment: @Christian.K That's why they're asking for help, no? Because they're doing it wrong.

Comment: Of course, and I'm trying to help. It might be enterily me misunderstanding the question, but I was under the impression that the given code doesn't work in "the way" the OP requires. I just don't see _exactly_ how it should work for them. Also, my suggestion that [this might not be a job for regex in the first place](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) was going in the direction that not using regex, but a simple StreamReader/StreamWrite approach might circumvent the memory issue, if any.

Comment: Basically what I need is to remove those line breaks by applying that regular expression but without iterating the file because it has many lines, it is large.

Comment: So, this will be my last comment - not to be harsh, but being out of time. (1) you insist on using the Regex, but at the same time (2) don't want to iterate the whole file, which is large. You _have_ to iterate the file, because there is no other magical way that can happen: bytes need to come off the disk, be changed, and written back to the disk. You can do it _piecewise_ to not overwhelm memory, but the I/O will have to happen. Whether you use a Regex or manual code doesn't change that.

Comment: @OscarJ You have to iterate the entire file, there is no way around this. Here is the basic pseudo-code `Read file line by line -> if the line ends with a pipe then append to new file with a trailing \n else append to new file without \n`

Comment: Line endings are CRLF, so try `(\w|\s+(?!\|))\r?\n`

Comment: Finally, the regular expression was not recognized by Regex. So what worked best for me is looping through the file and performing an expression one by one. Thanks to all for the help